# Añadir ceros a la izquierda del filename en Bash

Tags: bash, redshift

Estoy montando un script en `bash` para recrear la actividad de usuarios contra una base de datos en un nuevo clúster de `Amazon Redshift`. Para ello, he rescatado todas las queries lanzadas por usuarios durante un espacio de tiempo (2 horas) y la idea es repetir dichas queries durante 6/8 horas (es decir, el bloque se repetiría constantemente).

La nomenclatura de las queries es la siguiente: `X_idquery.sql`, donde `X` es un nº secuencial que va desde el 1 hasta el 5270 e `idquery` es el ID que tenía la consulta a la hora de rescatarla. Viendo como los ficheros se han ordenado al lanzar un `ll`, el primer bloque (de la query 1 a la 250), aparece así:

```sh
100_59638749.txt
101_59638750.txt
102_59638751.txt
103_59638752.txt
104_59638753.txt
105_59638754.txt
10_59638512.txt
106_59638756.txt
107_59638757.txt
108_59638759.txt
109_59638761.txt
110_59638765.txt
111_59638770.txt
112_59638788.txt
113_59638789.txt
114_59638791.txt
115_59638794.txt
11_59638522.txt
```

Es decir, no aparecen en el orden correcto (1, 2, 3, 4...).

¿Cómo podría añadir patrones de 0 delante del nombre del fichero para que quedaran ordenados? Es decir:

```sh
0001_idquery.sql
0002_idquery.sql
.
.
.
```

Ya que hay un total de 5270, la idea es que el patrón de la numeración anterior a idquery siempre tenga 4 dígitos.

Comment: Creo que no es necesario renombrar los archivos, solo léelos en "orden natural" con la opción `-v` de `ls`: `ls -v` (o `ll -v`).

Comment: @HernánAlarcón Pues tienes toda la razón, con ls -v hago el listado ordenado y lo puedo derivar a un fichero de texto para recorrerlo con un bucle. ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Esto te dará un listado basado en la fecha (más recientes al final), luego podrias simplemente iterar en orden.

```
ls -ltr
```

Pero si lo que deseas es cambiar tu código bash para obtener 0's a la izquierda (y tu especificar cuantos digitos quieres tener) puedes hacer uso de printf para procesar ese valor y luego concatenar el nombre de tu archivo

Ejemplo: Suponiendo que tengas un file tmp.txt con valores:

```
302453
50223424
101
2027
3038
```

y quieras tener definir 16 digitos como base valores por defecto. Este valor puede ser reemplazado por el que desees.

```
printf "%.16d\n" $(<tmp.txt)
0000000000302453
0000000050223424
0000000000000101
0000000000002027
0000000000003038
```

Quizá podrías hacer algo similar, por ejemplo dentro de un bucle donde X sea el valor incremental, luego concatenar el valor de $value a tu id.

```
value=printf "%.16d\n" $X
```

Espero que sea de ayuda!